# Type inference on generics in Dart

Tags: flutter, generics, dart, flutter-provider

If struggling to understand why the Dart type inference does not understand this structure with generics.

The question: Is it a limitation of the language or can I improve upon my code so that Dart understands the type of the returned variable?

My code is as follows.

```dart
class BaseState extends ChangeNotifier {
  static T of<T>(BuildContext context, {bool listen = true}) 
         => Provider.of<T>(context, listen: listen);

  static Future<T> dispatcher<E extends BaseEvent<T>, T extends BaseState>(BuildContext context, E event) 
         => of<T>(context, listen: false).dispatch<E, T>(event);

...
}
```

And I want to call it like this:

```dart
var newState = await BaseState.dispatcher(context, LoginToggleEvent());
print(newState.isLoggedIn);
```

The event `LoginToggleEvent` has a class definition of

```dart
abstract class AppEvent extends BaseEvent<AppState> {}
class LogginToggleEvent extends AppEvent {
 ...
}
```

And the `AppState` is a child class of `BaseState`.

The problem is that if I set it up like this, dart will say that the return type is a `BaseState` and I would expect it to be a `AppState`. Because the event E is an `AppEvent<AppState>`.

- If I change `var newState` to `AppState newState` it will work.
- If I explicitly cast it (as AppState) it will work.
- If I add explicit values for the dispatcher (`dispatcher<AppEvent, AppState>(..)`) it will work.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction or tell me that it can't be done.

Comment: Your first solution of exlicitly specifying `Type` of `newState` to `AppState` is the right way. In [effective dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#do-annotate-when-dart-infers-the-wrong-type) it is mentioned to specify the `Type` explicitly when `Type`  inference doesnt work as you expect.